# List of Data Orientation

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have list of data which I want to change for the sack of the layout.
**example**:

```
Name1 val1 val2 val3 val4
Name2 val5 val6 val7 val8
Name3 val9 val10 val11 val12
```

**Want to be like that:**

```
Name1 Name2 Name3
val1  val5  val9
val2  val6  val10
val3  val7  val11
val4  val8  val12
```

I'm using Asp.net Repeater to display that data
Thanks

Comment: Show your code here.

Comment: It's fairly simple, just one google away, If you want help with some problem paste your code here which is having problem